# File.AppendText() Slow

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I have one big file that is structured something like this:

```
 Report 1  section 1
 Report 2  section 1
 Report 1  section 2
 Report 3  section 1
 Report 2  section 2
 and so on....
```

I have to put all the 1s together, all the 2s together, etc, into Report 1, Report 2, Report 3.  I have no choice but to go line by line.  The problem is that it is very slow.  Here is the code I am using to write the files:

```
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(newFileName))
                    { sw.WriteLine(line); }
```

I think the problem is that the File.AppendText() is slowing down this process.  I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas about how to speed this up.

Comment: Do you mean you're reopening the file for every single line? Don't do that. (And don't format your source code like that, ideally...) Open the file once, right all the lines.

Comment: I can't do that because the files are huge and I have to read them line by line :(   Some lines need manipulating.

Comment: Well write to a temporary file first then. We don't really know what you're doing, but I'm sure there'll be a way of avoiding reopening the file for every line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are opening that file for each iteration. Try this:

```cs
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
{
    while (condition)
    {
        sw.WriteLine("write your line here");
    }
}
```

As Chris Berger has commented, you can nest usings like this

```cs
using (StreamWriter sw1 = File.AppendText(path1))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw2 = File.AppendText(path2))
    {
        while (condition)
        {
            if(writeInFile1)
                sw1.WriteLine("write your line here");
            else
                sw2.WriteLine("write your line here");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution however I will have five or six report files coming from one file.  I will try it and see if I can make it work.

Comment: @Missy- then sort the lines first, and write them all to one file at a time (one write per output file), if possible.

Comment: You can nest your usings to open several files at once if need be.  It would be kind of annoying to have 5 files open while running through code and doing processing, but it's probably better than the alternative.

edit: Or, as ps2goat says, group the lines first and write them to one file at a time.

Comment: Ok, the trick is a file must be open just once, if you need to fill more than one file, right, but open it, do what you need and close it.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in [Facundo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191037/file-appendtext-slow/41191393#comment69582183_41191171)

> This is a good solution however I will have five or six report files coming from one file...

You can open all 6 files at once by using multiple using statements.

```
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(source)
using (StreamWriter sw1 = File.AppendText(path1))
using (StreamWriter sw2 = File.AppendText(path2))
using (StreamWriter sw3 = File.AppendText(path3))
using (StreamWriter sw4 = File.AppendText(path4))
using (StreamWriter sw5 = File.AppendText(path5))
using (StreamWriter sw6 = File.AppendText(path6))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if(line.StartsWith("Report 1")
        {
            sw1.WriteLine(line);
        }
        else if(line.StartsWith("Report 2")
        {
            sw2.WriteLine(line);
        }
        else if(line.StartsWith("Report 3")
        {
            sw3.WriteLine(line);
        }
        else if(line.StartsWith("Report 4")
        {
            sw4.WriteLine(line);
        }
        else if(line.StartsWith("Report 5")
        {
            sw5.WriteLine(line);
        }
        else if(line.StartsWith("Report 6")
        {
            sw6.WriteLine(line);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidDataException($"Line does not start with a report number: \n{line}");
        }
    }
}
```